# extending the security trimmed control for groups

Tags: 2013, security-trimming

I want to show a button just for a sharepoint group. Is it possible from the master page or with javascript? I mean without extending the sp security trimmed control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each web part in the web part properties you can set a target audience.

To do this: Click `Edit page` -> On the web part you want to security trim click `Edit Web Part` -> Under `Advanced` tab at the very bottom you should see `Target Audiences`.

Click the address book, change the scope to `SharePoint Groups`, and search for the group you want to see the button.